# Can multiple load balancers point to the same upstream server?

Tags: nginx, high-availability

I have the following set up where LB-00 and LB-01 are Nginx load balancers

```
LB-00 ---> SERVER-00
LB-01 ---> SERVER-01
```

I want to know if the following is possible

```
LB-00 ---> SERVER-00
LB-01 ---> SERVER-00
```

Configure LB-00 and then reload the configuration

Note that all traffic flows through LB-01

Would this affect the upstream servers?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. There is no limitation in doing so. Just be sure that SERVER-00 accepts requests from both LB (in case you use some kind of firewall like iptables).